# Error while connecting to a remote solr instance from Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am using Sunspot rails(1.1.0). Everything works when I run my Rails
application and the Solr server on the same machine. When I run Solr
server on a different machine, I get the following error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - Connection refused
from /opt/tibco/jruby-1.4.0RC1/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize'
from /opt/tibco/jruby-1.4.0RC1/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `new'
from /opt/tibco/jruby-1.4.0RC1/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'
```

After debugging through Sunspot code, I realized that the Solr::Client is connecting to `localhost` rather than the remote host configured in `sunspot.yml`. My sunspot.yml file is as follows:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: kingkong
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
```

The `build_session` method(sunspot_rails-1.1.0/lib/rails.rb:line 24) tries to establish a slave session. The slave_config method ignores the configuration provided in sunspot.yml file. Here is the `slave_config` method:

```
def slave_config(sunspot_rails_configuration)
  config = Sunspot::Configuration.build
  config.solr.url = URI::HTTP.build(
    :host => configuration.hostname,
    :port => configuration.port,
    :path => configuration.path
  ).to_s
  config
end
```

Is this the intended behavior? Also, has anybody successfully connected to Solr running remotely?

**Note:**

I was able to work around this issue by monkey patching the
Sunspot::Rails.slave_config method. I added file called sunspot.rb in
configurations/initializers directory.

```
module Sunspot::Rails
  def slave_config(sunspot_rails_configuration)
    config = Sunspot::Configuration.build
    config.solr.url = URI::HTTP.build(
      :host => sunspot_rails_configuration.hostname,
      :port => sunspot_rails_configuration.port,
      :path => sunspot_rails_configuration.path
    ).to_s
    config
  end
end
Sunspot.session = Sunspot::Rails.build_session
```

I am not sure if this is the correct approach. Please let me know if I am missing something basic.

Comment: I have seen this odd issue with connectivity in Sunspot around slave versus master, mostly in older versions.  So it might very well be likely!

Comment: Did you get it working ?

Comment: @PamioSolanky Look at my note in the answer

Comment: Thanks, Ignored that completely :)